# How can I set the value of users id number in my object when it is created?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-domain-class

I'm using spring-security-core and want to mark a newly created object with the id of the user that created it.
I've tried to use the following code but the value in the database is always zero even if I put a constant in return from getUserID. However the default setting of DateCreated works.

```
class test {
    def springSecurityService

    Date        dateCreated
    int                 createdBy

    static mapping = { 
        dateCreated column: "dateCreated",     defaultValue: newDate()
        createdBy       column: "createdBy",       defaultValue: getUserID()
}

def getUserID() {
    def user = springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() ?
        springSecurityService.loadCurrentUser() :
        null
    return user.id
}
```

}

Comment: `I've tried to use the following code but the value in the database is always zero` But *what* value in the database is "always zero"?

Comment: It's of course the field: "createdBy" that wasn't updated with the defaultvalue.

Comment: BTW, your `geUserID()` can throw NullPointerException

Comment: Yes I noticed it, hoped that no one  else would find it before I fixed it. ;-) Well I made an edit on it and think that it would protect me from an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why the value of createdBy was zero in the database when I set the value in the static mapping when the other field dateCreated was updated in DB.

But I solved my problem by setting the value of createdBy in the "beforeInsert" procedure.
So here is my solution:

```
class Test
    Date        dateCreated
    int         createdBy 

    def beforeInsert() {
        createdBy = getUserID()
    }
    def int getUserID() {
        def user = springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() ?
            springSecurityService.loadCurrentUser() :
            null
        return user ? user.id: -1
    }
    static mapping = { 
        dateCreated column: "dateCreated",     defaultValue: newDate()
    }

}
```

Comment: question is why firstly not bind to actual User object. 2nd why call something createdBy then getUserId - difficult to follow - 3rd does your domain class really need to have that logic to work out user at the low level ? could the controller / service/ validation class not set that before attempting to save ?

Comment: First, the field "createdBy" should show which user created this object so it's stored within the object. Then the function "getUserID" is fetching this ID. I've tried a lot of different things and this solution is the that worked. And as already said, I have no idea why this couldn't be done the same way as I did with dateCreated. Second: I don't know what you mean with "bind to actual user"? Third, I think it's very good to let these 2 fields getting their values in the domain class, they will never change.

Comment: Also, I have a problem getting service to work so I have to do things as simple as possible otherwise I'll never be finished. These things will be corrected later when I learned these things better.

Answer (score 0):

First, the field "createdBy" should show which user created this object so it's stored within the object. Then the function "getUserID" is fetching this ID. I've tried a lot of different things and this solution is the that worked. And as already said, I have no idea why this couldn't

Okay but you are storing an int which has a process to get the long number of the userId and store it as an integer value.

Now in reverse each time you need to find the actual user you will need to get that id and do a `User.get(createdBy)` to bind to the real User class 
So instead of

```
int createdBy
```

try

```
User createdBy
```

`I don't know what you mean with "bind to actual user"`

This means you are binding the createdBy id as a real object in the domain class so when looking up you already have the user object and no need to do a User.get on each integer. Lots of DB look ups per listing etc vs having the real object there is no real difference in the DB design/context it is just a real object vs flat number.

**Very important point above**

Secondly my point of injecting services in each domain class to automatically set just the user is kind of daft expensive and really no need. The entire adding process should be done through a service and in that call you simply do `userService.currentUser`

Sounds like you are having problems getting user ?
class UserService {

```
def getCurrentUser() {
    def principal = springSecurityService?.principal
    String username = principal?.username
    if (username) {
        return find(username)
    }
}
def find(String user) {
    return User.findByUsername(user)
}
```

}

so now `userService.currentUser` will give you your actual user object for spring security

so far as dateCreated and lastUpdated they are both dynamic fields in grails and nothing additional required. By default just an entry in domain class is all that is needed. It will automtically set those values

Hope you are a little clearer ?